# Full text search in all columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I was using the following query in PostgreSQL and I investigate if there is any similar for Oracle 19c:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE table_name::TEXT LIKE '%some_text%';
```

The best alternative that I can find for Oracle is the following but I am wondering if there is any better approach.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE
   COALESCE(to_char(column1), '') || 
   COALESCE(to_char(column2), '') || 
   COALESCE(to_char(columnN), '') 
LIKE '%some_text%';
```

Comment: What difference do you expect between `COALESCE(to_char(column1), '')` and `to_char(column1)`? And if it's a text column, isn't that the same thing as `column1`? If it's not a text column, what kind of value are you searching for in it?

Comment: In my case the schema is defined dynamically, so a column can be of type CLOB and it may include a json string for example or a DATE. With PostgreSQL I had the flexibility to do a full text search without knowing the column names while I guess in Oracle this cannot be achieved.

Comment: I just wondered about the `coalesce` and `to_char` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will give false positives where half the text is in one column and the second half of the text is in the next column. You can use `OR` and filter on each column:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column1 LIKE '%some_text%'
OR     column2 LIKE '%some_text%'
-- ...
OR     columnN LIKE '%some_text%';
```

*Note: you can also skip filtering the non-string columns.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what you are saying is that if column1 is "Hello" and column2 is "World", if I search for '%HelloWorld%' it will pick the row?

Comment: @georgeliatsos Using your code in the question, yes. Using the code in this answer, no. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=84f5b754f977b8416ede30a831cb47c9)